# Problems with spl_autoload_register()

Tags: php

I do have a problem with one of my php application. First of all my test environment is running on IIS with PHP installed. There I have the following code:

```
<?php
// define autoloader for all php classes
$ps = PATH_SEPARATOR; // add default path seperator to a variable
set_include_path(get_include_path().$ps."classes/adapter/".$ps."classes/common/".$ps."classes/manager/".$ps."classes/mapper/".$ps."classes/object/".$ps."classes/viewobject/"); // add classes directory to include paths
spl_autoload_extensions(".class.php"); // add .class.php as extension for autoloading classes
spl_autoload_register(); //start the autoloading procedure
?>
```

So far so good, since this is working as it should. Now I wanted to move that page to my provider which uses Apache with PHP and what I see there is the following error message:

```
Fatal error: spl_autoload() [<a href='function.spl-autoload'>function.spl-autoload</a>]: Class pageLoader could not be loaded
```

Do you guys may have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Do the php versions match in the two environments? Are you aware that linux filesystems are case-sensitive?

Comment: What version of PHP do you have on production and on dev? Is the class namespaced?

Comment: Check the value of the argument going into the `set_include_path()` function.

Comment: I am aware that linux is case-sensitive and that shouldn't be the problem. The PHP Version on my Dev is 5.3.10 and the PHP version on the prod is 5.2.4. I did also verify that my include path have been set as expected. Are the different PHP versions causing the issue?

Comment: hey guys, looks like I found the issue.. I was aware that linux is case-sensitive, but for any reason the filenames of the classes have to be in small letters. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like I found the issue.. I was aware that linux is case-sensitive, but for any reason the filenames of the classes have to be in small letters.

In my example if you make a call

```
$test = new pageLoader();
```

The file in the directory needs to have the name "pageloader.class.php"

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to define the loader function?

```
// Autoloader for Classes
spl_autoload_register(null, false); // Nullify any existing autoloads
spl_autoload_extensions('.php, .class.php'); // Specify extensions that may be loaded

function class_loader($class) // Class loader
{
    $filename = strtolower($class) .'.class.php';
    $file = ROOT .'/classes/'. $filename;

    if(!is_readable($file))
        return false;

    require_once $file;
}

spl_autoload_register('class_loader'); // Register loader function(s)
// End Autoloader
```

Note the code above assumes a defined constant `ROOT`

Comment: No need - http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php - "This function is intended to be used as a default implementation for __autoload(). If nothing else is specified and spl_autoload_register() is called without any parameters then this function will be used for any later call to __autoload()."